# Several Exceptions with WebClient DownloadString()

Tags: c#

I am using the following snippet to download string:

```
private const string url = "http://www.cninnovation.com";

static async Task Main()
{
    SynchronizedAPI();
}


private static void SynchronizedAPI()
{
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(SynchronizedAPI));
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {

            string content = client.DownloadString(url);
            Console.WriteLine(content.Substring(0, 100));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
}
```

With the above snippet I got 3 exceptions:

1. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
2. IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
3. SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Comment: Please add the full Stack Trace of the errors you're getting.

Comment: Post the exceptions and inspect the HTTP status code. Although it's quite likely that web site doesn't like screen scrapers so it terminates connections to anything that doesn't look like a web browser.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using `HttpClient` instead

```
static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

static async Task Main()
{
  try   
  {
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.cninnovation.com");
     string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();    
     Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
  }
  catch(HttpRequestException e)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: The main benefit of HttpClient in this case is checking the response status code *without* throwing an exception, or reading the body